# Why is notification manager (notify) method is so expensive for memory when loop?

Tags: android

```
while (key){
    builder.setNumber(++numMessages);
    manager.notify(notifyID, builder.build());
}
```

- this lines of code make the device lag and increase the allocated
  memory rapidly.
- this is a small picture of my problem in showing time of mediaplayer
  (Audio) in the notification so, I have to update time every 100
  millisecond.
- **Any suggestion or solution for this problem?**

Comment: this doc may help you: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Progress

Comment: nope I went over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notifications involve sending all of the data, including every Bitmap, from your application to the Android system. Prior to Android 7.0, this caused the data to be entirely copied before being sent over.

Of course, media players should be using [MediaStyle notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html#mediastyle-notifications) which are specifically designed for things like playback controls. They do not show the current playing time.

However, if you really need to show the current time, you should instead use [setUsesChronometer(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setUsesChronometer(boolean)) which changes the time set with [setWhen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setWhen(long)) into the start of a timer which will automatically update every second without you having to call `notify` every second.

Comment: Hey lan, thank you for your response. This solve my main issue which is lagging. Also, allocated memory was stable. But there is a point that I can't solve. I tried to stop time from counting when audio stop but i failed.. chrommeter(true) when setwhen(system.timeinMili - timeElapsed).  I am so limited with the stack design so I used a remoteview with the notification and a receiver to control my media player action by pending intent but it is hard to control memory even if i create another Thread to the main Thread to do the time counting job. Setwhen () method is not usable with remoteview.

Comment: Yeah, you really should switch to `MediaStyle` and remove your custom `RemoteViews` if you want to be consistent with every other media player